# passing javascript block through the template unescaped

Tags: hugo

I want to include Reactjs code in my content like this:

```
<script type="text/babel">

  ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <a href="http://www.example.com">this is a link...</a>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );

</script>
```

I want this code to actual run, not just for display. However, when it passes through the Hugo template it comes out as:

```
<p><script type="text/babel"></p>

<pre><code>  ReactDOM.render(
    &lt;div&gt;
      &lt;h1&gt;Hello, world!&lt;/h1&gt;
      &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.example.com&quot;&gt;this is a link...&lt;/a&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );

&lt;/script&gt;
</code></pre>
```

which means it won't run.

Basically, I want content editors to be able to drop in a React Component code and have it run on the page. Thanks.

EDIT:
This is what I want to be the final output of the hugo template:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js">
</script>
  </head>
 <body>

   <div id="root"></div>

   <script type="text/babel">

     ReactDOM.render(
       <div>
         <h1>Hello!!</h1>
         <a href="http://www.example.com">this is a link...</a>
       </div>,
       document.getElementById('root')
     );

   </script>


 </body>
</html>
```

but I want the bit between the script tags to be entered in to the markdown page as it will be surrounded by other text, and should not form part of the template

Comment: Aren't you thinking upside down here? A react component is already a template in itself... If you want users to be able to decide which templates are being displayed, then that choice should be a part of the template.

Comment: So, I want editors to be able to add the component code into the page, not the template

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I worked out the problem.

In order to get this to work you need to make sure that the open

```
<script>
```

tag has no whitespace to the left. It must start the line. Otherwise, I guess the template engine will just go ahead and escape it.